# Redirect to another page without confirmation

Tags: url, redirect, oracle-apex

I have a textbox. I want to logout current page and session without any confirmation and redirect to Login page when user enter "exit" in the textbox. any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that text item's name is P3_TEXT. Set its "Submit when Enter pressed" property to YES. Create a process whose PL/SQL code looks like this:

```
begin
  if lower(:P3_TEXT) = 'exit' then 
     apex_authentication.logout(:SESSION, :APP_ID);
  end if;
end;
```

Run the page; if you put "exit" into the text item and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, you'll be logged out.

**[EDIT]**

Previous Apex versions (3.1 for sure) had the [APEX_CUSTOM_AUTH.LOGOUT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10513_01/apirefs.310/e12855/apex_auth.htm#BABICDIB) procedure whose 3rd parameter was `p_next_url` you could have set to - for example - Login page. It is now deprecated (I believe you'll get the error if you try to use it).

Now (in the recent Apex version), navigate to application's Shared Components - Authentication Scheme. In there, you'll see the Post-Logout URL section which can be set to

- Home page, or
- URL

so - pick one that best suits your needs.

Comment: Thank you Littlefoot, Your code is right and it just close the session. After closing the session I want to redirect to Login page. What is the solution for this??

Comment: @Professor, I edited my message; have a look, please.

Comment: I have done it. But just I have : page error  : Your session has expired. And no redirect happens...

Comment: I have added the process with the PL/SQL code. I have added the URL of Login page in Shared Components => Post-Logout. The process terminate the session but there is no redirect to Login page

Comment: Could you specify that URL you used?

Comment: What happens if you include login page number, such as `.../f?p=110:101` (100 is application number, 101 is page number)?

Comment: @Littlefoot what if the URL changes dynamically?

Comment: The one you'd like to redirect to upon exit, @dmak2709? I wouldn't know, sorry. But, that's not often, is it? People usually redirect to one predefined URL.